# How to get data from json objects

Tags: android, json

How to get the particular data object from the JSON data from the given JSON data:

```
{
    "customer":{
        "id":1117198024800,
        "email":"abc@gmail.com",
        "accepts_marketing":false
    }
}
```

I need to parse ID from the above data, Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: so how your getting this json can you tell me ?

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: @Ashish  JSONObject responceObj = new JSONObject(data);

                //getting customer id from JSON data

                JSONObject childObj = responceObj.getJSONObject("customer");
                for(int k=0;k<childObj.length();k++){
                    //long id = childObj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(0)).getLong("id");

                    long id = childObj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(0)).optLong("id");
                }

Comment: see here  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parse-json-java/

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
  JSONObject responceObj = new JSONObject(data);
     JSONObject customer= response.getJSONObject("customer");
           String id= customer.getString("id");
           String email= customer.getString("email"); 
           String accepts_marketing= customer.getString("accepts_marketing");
```

Comment: I'm not getting the response of the Id since it is long type, tell me how it was done by you

Answer (score 1):

If you will use it as string:

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(data);
JSONObject customer = reader.getJSONObject("customer");
String id = (String) customer.getString("id");
```

Comment: I'm not getting the response of the Id since it is long type, tell me how it was done by you

Comment: JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(data);
JSONObject customer = reader.getJSONObject("customer");
long id = customer.getLong("id");

Answer (score 0):

add to app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1"
  }
```

In code:

```
     String string = "{
            \"customer\":{
                \"id\":1117198024800,
                \"email\":\"abc@gmail.com\",
                \"accepts_marketing\":false
            }
        }";
        java.lang.reflect.Type type = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<HashMap<String,Customer>>() {}.getType();
        HashMap<String, Customer> hashMap = new Gson().fromJson(string, type).
        Customer customer = hashMap.get("customer");
```

Customer.java class:

```
 public class Customer{
    Long id;
    String email;
    Boolean acceptsMarketing;
 }
```